# Merging Two Folders Into One in OS X?

Tags: folders, macos

When trying to drag various items into a folder in Finder in OS X and some of the items have the same name, OS X will ask if you wish to replace the items in the folder you are dragging to.

However if you wish to merge the files from the first folder to the second folder:

How do you accomplish this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the folders are the same name, drag one to the location of the other, and BEFORE releasing the mouse or trackpad, hold down the `Option` key. You will be presented with three options, one of which is to Merge.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, holding down the Option key will **Copy** instead of **Move** the files.